# Ubuntu Virtual Machine cant' mount directories /dev /sys /proc

Tags: boot, mount, virtualbox

I am running this Ubuntu Virtual machine on CentOS5- Virtual Host Manager.

The Virtual machine can't boot because it can't mount /dev,/sys,/proc.

Killed:
mount: mounting /dev on root/dev failed: no such file or direcotry
mount:          /sys  failed
mount:          /proc failed
target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
no init found. Try passing init=bootarg

BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash_

(initranfs)

I read about booting with liveCd...but how do i fix it in a virtual machine.

Please Help.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't know anything about you problem (mounting issue), but of course you can use a live system CD/DVD in a virtual machine. Just either insert it into your physical machine and tell the VM host to attach the drive to the vm or directly let it mount the iso image as virtual CD drive.